# iterate over "looped" array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Let's say I've got an array like this:

```
let arr = [1,2,3....36,38,39]; //an array of 39 elements
```

'looped' in the title refers to the fact that when iterating over the array forwards, the iteration jumps from `arr[39]` to `arr[0]`, and the same is true for going from `arr[0]` to `arr[39]` - in essence, the array is a closed loop.

In my code I am alternating the direction of iteration and the starting and end index of each such step-through is predetermined:

```
arr[0] //initial condition is always the same
arr[5]
arr[17]
arr[30]
arr[14]
etc.
```

My question is such - is there a simple way of determining which way of iteration is 'shorter', taking the gap between arr[39] and arr[0] into account?

That is, when the iteration is at arr[35] and the next instruction is to go to arr[2] it's closer to go through the 'gap' taking 6 steps instead of going backwards and taking 33 steps.

Comment: Yes, simple modulo maths

Comment: Are you trying to figure out whether it's faster to go "through the gap" vs *not* "through the gap" *regardless of forwards/backwards*? Or trying to figure out whether it's faster to go *forwards* vs *backwards*?

Comment: @TylerRoper sorry if it wasn't clear. Consider the array being a circle with the first and last indices being neighbors. forwards/backwards direction (i++ vs i--) would have to be determined by which way is faster to reach from one index to another (that is - going from 37 to 2 is faster forwards and through the gap, but going from 20 to 7 is faster backwards not through the gap)

Answer (score 2):

How about using the `slice` method to get a count of the differences in both directions? It might work well because you can use negative numbers to calculate what the number of items would be when 'jumping the gap' I'm assuming you might be traversing the array in either direction, so you could be going from something like `[2] -> [35]` or `[36] -> [35]` not necessarily always forward.

```
function shortestPath (idx1, idx2, array) {
  const min = Math.min(idx1, idx2);
  const max = Math.max(idx1, idx2);

  const straight = array.slice(min, max).length;
  const looped = array.slice(max - array.length).length + array.slice(0, min).length;

  return (straight < looped)
    ? 'straight' : 'jump the gap';
}

const array = new Array(40);
shortestPath(2, 35, array) // 'jump the gap'
shortestPath(35, 2, array) // 'jump the gap'
shortestPath(36, 35, array) // 'straight'
shortestPath(35, 36, array) // 'straight'
```

I don't have any error checking or anything if you give it indexes beyond the array.length or negative numbers etc... but that should give you a start. It works because `slice` lets you use negative numbers as the beginning. So `slice(-2)` says give me the last two items. This way instead of grabbing the middle of the array we can grab the items on either side of the two indexes, then add them together.

Answer (score 0):

Given `m` size of array, `i` and `j` being actual and next `index` respectively, then:

```
if(Math.abs(i - j) > Math.abs(i - (m + j))) {
    // use gap
} else {
    // go straight
}
```

You can think about this gap like a second array joined right after first one. if so, then next index will be `m + j`.